# How to check if linux file is empty with python script?

Tags: python, bash

I have a python script that needs to check if a log file is empty or has logs in it.
I use the os.system in order to run bash commands, found this command in order to find if file is empty or not:

```
if [ -s /tmp/myfile.txt ]
then
     echo "File not empty"
else
     echo "File empty"
fi
```

I tried just to write this in one line inside the os.system command but i get an error:

sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

To test whether a file is empty, you can use `os.stat`:

```
import os

def is_empty(filename):
    return os.stat(filename).st_size == 0
```